# ParameterBag could not be converted to string laravel 5.5

Tags: php, symfony, laravel-5.5

This my Code:

```
public function storeQuery(Request $request)
{            
    $q = new Query;

     //query table  
    //input lines
    $qr = $q->save(); //Getting Error here

    return view('caller.loader');

}
```

Here is Errors:

> Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string

I could not get it.

Comment: `$q = new Query;`  need to be:- `$q = new Query();`

Comment: @AlivetoDie it should be, but thats not the root of the error - you don't need the parens

Comment: @Sayandeep: I assume you would have a call trace to that error. Do you?

Comment: @JovanPerovic Yes. And I wrote same code for InputCustomer which is ok

Comment: Without looking into the code snippet, there is very little I can offer here...  Can you provide some code that actually interacts with that `Query` object?

Comment: Query is a Model class in laravel5.5. That's it @Jovan
I'm posting the Code:  
        $customer = new Customer;
        $customer->ph                   = $request->ph;
        $customer->email_id             = $request->email;
      $cust_result = $customer->save();

Comment: This is the same code like Query. This is running perfectly

Answer (score 25):

You are probably doing something like `$request->query`

`$request->query` is an object of type ParameterBag which contains the Query Params for GET Requests.

You should rather use `$request->get('query')` in these circumstances

Answer (score 1):

For me it was turned out that I was using the key `query` as request parameter.
Changing it to some other parameters solved the problem.